# How can I add multiple languages in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?

Tags: language-support, ubuntu-gnome

It is easy to add and change languages in Ubuntu with the default Unity desktop environment.
You just have to to Languages & Support -> <kbd>Install / Remove Languages...</kbd> and add which ever you want.

How can I do the same in **Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?**

[image]

Adding Input Sources without adding corresponding language results in unsupported characters :

[image]

Comment: If you click on the `Language    English (United States)` line, what happens?

Comment: @muru No kannada available. It was available on ubuntu unity.

Comment: @muru It gets replaced, I tried with some other language. `Language English (United States)` will be overwritten . Can't have both simultaneously :-(

Comment: Try installing Kannada and then setting English (US) again as the default.

Comment: @muru Kannada is missing :| see this : [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J974G.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is inadvisable on GNOME to install the `language-selector-gnome` as it is a Unity tool and manages to interfere with the pre-installed system for dealing with language packs and input sources (especially with the IBus).

The built-in method to install additional language packs (and you have to install the language pack before you can add the input source) is as follows:

1. Go to the `Region & Language` section of the `gnome-control-center`:

[image: Region & Language section button]

2. Click on `Language` in order to get the language selection up:

[image: Language button]

3. Click the button at the bottom to offer more languages than the currently install ones:

[image: More languages button]

4. In the search box at the bottom search for the language you want to install.
5. Select the language(s) you wish to install (a tick will appear next to the selected languages) and then click `Done`.
6. After doing so a box similar to do this one will appear, check that you are happy with what will be installed and then click `Install`, you will be prompted for authentication and may get another installation box on which you should also click `Install` if you get it:

[image: Install additional language packs dialog]

---

**Note:** If there is a language that you find can only be installed properly for some reason through the `language-selector-gnome` install it through there but after doing so purge the `language-selector-gnome`, then you will get the language pack you want, but the program won't interfere with your system.

Comment: The claim, that `language-selector-gnome` interferes with system for language packs and input sources in Ubuntu GNOME, needs to be backed up. There indeed was a reason for confusion for a short period, but it has been [fixed in 16.04](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1551283). It's simply not true, AFAIK, that the pure presence of `language-selector-gnome` makes a difference. So Paranoid Panda, if you can show such an example (in 16.04), I'd appreciate if you could give me the details, because then it's a bug which should be fixed.

Comment: Are you the reporter of that bug? :) No, that's not the case. The seemingly double instances of IBus is related to `im-config`, not `language-selector-gnome`. (And it shouldn't prevent you from installing Anthy. I tested it intensively when working with that bug.)

Comment: Let me remind you about [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1551283/comments/50) at the bug report.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, *Region & Language* in Ubuntu GNOME does basically the same as *Language Support* (`language-selector-gnome`) when it comes to adding languages, even if the UIs differ. However, you are right about Kannada - for some (to me unknown) reason it's available as a language in *Language Support*, but not in *Region & Language*.

When you add a language, some language support is installed besides the translations, including extra fonts if applicable. So it's advisable to install the language first if you are about to add an input source for some non-latin script. This is true for both Ubuntu GNOME and other flavors.

With that said, and even if *Language Support* is not installed by default in Ubuntu GNOME, it's compatible with Ubuntu GNOME, and can be useful as a supplement occationally.

Answer (score 2):

Since the idea with Ubuntu GNOME is to provide GNOME software, the default tool is *Region & Language*.

To get *Language support*, the package `language-selector-gnome` has to be installed.

So install `language-selector-gnome` to add and change languages in the way you used to do.

Execute : `sudo apt install language-selector-gnome`.

Now any language can be added and configured as usual.

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `language-selector-gnome` is not accidentally "missing". It's not present by default since the idea with Ubuntu GNOME is to provide GNOME software, and the corresponding GNOME tool is _Region & Language_.

Comment: yes! Its included now :) @GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: Nice improvement. :)

Comment: I wouldn't advise the installing of the `language-selector-gnome` package on GNOME, that would be rather advised as it does cause some problems with the IBus and is not needed to install additional language packs.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Please see my comment to your answer.